# Is it okay to use IDE JPA wizards to generate tables from entities? or should I strive to do everything manually?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa, netbeans

I mean wizards such as JPA Tools in Eclipse which can help me generate tables from entities or entities from tables.

Or is it best practice to do everything manually?

Answer (score 3):

These types of wizards are incredibly useful, but they rarely get everything 100% correct.  I suggest using them to create the initial schema but then do any fine tuning yourself and check the result carefully.

Often the quality of the schema created depends greatly on the detail that you supply in your annotations.  The better the annotations the more likely your schema is generated correctly (for example make sure you specify the length attribute against String columns to ensure they are sized correctly in the database).

Answer (score 0):

Generating table from entities is ok. If you have to do it the other way around (generating entities from table), it's best to do it manually.